# Thread Safety - Making Binary Search Tree thread safe

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, posix

I'm fairly new to programming in C and also Threading as well.

I am working on creating functions for a Binary Search Tree such as Insert, Search & Delete. But I have been specified to make these functions thread safe.

So my question is how can I make these functions thread safe, what do I need to do? And any general advice on Threading?

As an example: I've made a start on a search function, but how would you make that thread safe? Is there like easy common things you can do to make make these thread safe?

```
int search (node* root, int number)
{
    if(root==NULL)
      return 0;
    else if(number==root->data)
      return 1;
    else if(number<=root->data)
      return search(root->left,number);
    else 
      return search(root->right,number);
}
```

I'm using POSIX.

Comment: Have you done any research? Such as searching for "make c code thread safe"?

Comment: Your main choices are One Big Lock, or multi-reader/single-writer lock depending on expected workload.

Comment: @stark One big lock? what would this look like ?

Comment: One mutex around all accesses.  Don't bother trying anything else unless you get performance issues later.  Correctness first, performance later:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to make your program thread safe, though a [thread library exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) in the C standard for thread synchronization and simple mutual exclusion mechanisms, more complex features are usually dependent on the Operating System and its libraries, Win API, POSIX, etc.

You should start with a simple mutex. All things considered may be the the best approach in your particular case.

Using POSIX, you declare and initialize the mutex where you launch and sync the threads:

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;

if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
    puts("Unable to create mutex!");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

And pass it as pointer in the thread argument structure.

Inside the threads you use `pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)` and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)` to secure the critical section, ***i.e.*** the part of the code where the data race occurs, not more not lesss, ***only*** the places where the shared data is accessed or modified, being extra careful with the deadlocks.

I'm assuming you know how to create and synchronize threads, if not here you have a very thourough tutorial on how to do it (it also approaches mutexes):

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html

Mutual exclusion is one of the simplest concurrency conflicts solving mechanisms, and as [eugenioperez very accurately pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3473433/eugenioperez), this may be achieved using C standard features lending your program more portability, using the aforementioned `<threads.h>` library.

Comment: Oh yeah should have said, I believe it is POSIX that should be used, how would that Mutex look like here ?

Comment: @BarCode, you declare it and initialize it where you launch the threads and pass it as pointer in the thread argument structure, inside the threads you use pthread_mutex_lock and unlock to secure the critical section, ***i.e.*** where the data race occurs. I added more info to my answer.

Comment: As a small nitpick, some multithreading synchronization mechanism are defined in the C11 standard in <threads.h> (`mtx_t`, `mtx_init()`, `mtx_lock`, ...) with a very similar usage to posix ones. If the complier does not implement them, very thin wrappers libraries exists over posix, windows, etc, making the code more portable if it is worth.